# Make appendix files work for both book and article document classes

Tags: sectioning

I have a book with chapters, sections, subsections, etc.
I frequently want to distribute a single chapter of the book as a stand-alone article.
To do this, I just write a replacement preamble setting the documentclass to article.

There's a catch.
In the book class the appendices are marked with the `\chapter` command, but in the article class they're marked with `\section`.

Is there an easy way to make the same appendix files work for both classes?

My solution so far has been to make a new command I call `varsec` which takes two arguments:

1. The type of section (chapter, section, subsection).
2. The name of the section.

I mark the appendices as `\varsec{chapter}`, and then in the article preamble I make `\varsec{chapter}` produce `\section`, while in the book preamble I make it produce `\chapter`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It might be better if you explained what you actually *want* to achieve because the finer nuances of the technical term "organizational chunk" may be lost on many of the readers of TeX.SX:) It is quite likely that you can achieve what you want by setting `tocdepth` etc to appropriate values. Another approach, which I use, is to include your chapters as separate files using `\include` commands., Then youcan use `\includeonly{...}` to print only certain chapters.

Comment: @Andrew I understand the value of explaining what one wants to achieve instead of asking how to execute a particular task. However, I think I *did* explain what I want to achieve in the post, so I need some feedback. What's unclear?

Comment: Daniel, as I said, I have no idea what an "organizational chunk" is. Further, the most likely interpretation can be catered for using standard latex flags such as `tocdepth`. You should explain what you want to do in terms of layout rather than in terms of redefining commands as there may well be easier ways to achieve the desired output.

Comment: try this `\let\artappendix\appendix\renewcommand\appendix{\artappendix\let\chapter\section}` in article preambl

Comment: @Andrew: Ok, I think I improved it significantly.

Comment: @touhami can you explain what that's doing? Why not make it an answer?

Comment: You could also have a look at package `coseoul`.

Comment: i will make it an answer (but just a question why this is problem in appendices and not others chapters and are there sections in appendix?)

Comment: @touhami yes, there are sections in the appendix. It's only a problem in appendices because I already have my chapter headings broken out into their own files which `\subimport*` the various sections. I realize I could extend that principle further, but it becomes unwieldy.

Comment: @Johannes_B that is probably the most useful TeX package I've ever seen. Thank you.

Comment: OK, now an other question, you want all the appendices as one article? the problem is you will break the hierarchy by makeing `\chapter` `section` don't think so may be make chapters as parts is better

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is the code of book

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{first}% or \include
\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{first appe}% or \include
\lipsum
\chapter{first appe}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

this will be the article

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\chapter\part
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{first appe}% or \include
\lipsum
\chapter{first appe}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sort of works, but does unhappy things to the TOC.

Comment: @DanielSank what do you mean exactly

Comment: Did you try compiling your example with a TOC? The pieces marked as `\part` get bigger font in the TOC. The headings in the document are also bigger than the headings for the `\section`s.

Comment: @DanielSank this is the idea, otherwise you canreplace `\part` by `\section`

Comment: Yeah, using `\section` is much better. Still better is to use my own label, e.g. `\appendix` and then set that to either `\chapter` or `\section`, which is roughly what is proposed in OP, but your idea of using `\let` is better than using a two argument macro.

Comment: I will try some variations of this and see what works well.

Comment: @DanielSank for me it's not so complicated, there is 2 choices (a) use the `coseoul` package if you plan to do this régulary (b) `\let\chapter\part` if not and you still can redefine the style of parts as you need. Let me ask, why did you split your appendix to chapters in the first place?

Comment: I split the appendices into chapters because, as far as I know, for the book class that's how you have multiple appendices. Each appendix is a chapter.

Comment: @DanielSank What i mean is that a chapter is for section as US for New York

Comment: I understand now. The reason is that in the book class, by making each appendix a chapter, each one is automatically named in a reasonable way: Appendix A, Appendix B, etc.